# ArgumentError: argument 3: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type

Tags: python, anaconda, kivy

I'm testing kivy on win10 via nimiconda.

Everytime when I run(press F5 on miniconda,the same as anaconda) the kivy code for the second time,the consel will throw "ArgumentError: argument 3: : wrong type"

I test the kivy code by Miniconda3(also test it in Anaconda3,the same issus appeard),Every time I press F5 for the first time, the code runs normally,and kivy interface appears normally, as follow:

```
runfile('C:/Users/38477/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/38477/.spyder-py3')

[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\38477\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-07-20_1.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "G:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 17:13:21) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "G:\Miniconda3\pythonw.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.0.0 - Build 10.18.10.4885'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.00 - Build 10.18.10.4885'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [WindowSDL   ] exiting mainloop and closing.
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
```

but after colsing kivy interface ,pressing F5 will report the following error.

```
runfile('C:/Users/38477/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/38477/.spyder-py3')
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[ERROR  ] [Base        ] No event listeners have been created
[ERROR  ] [Base        ] Application will leave
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-2-83710e3ec7f9>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/38477/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/38477/.spyder-py3')

File"G:\Miniconda3\lib\sitepackages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
   execfile(filename, namespace)

File "G:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

 File "C:/Users/38477/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 15, in <module>
   TestApp().run()

 File "G:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 855, in run
   runTouchApp()

 File "G:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 506, in runTouchApp
   stopTouchApp()

 File "G:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 521, in stopTouchApp
   EventLoop.close()

 File "G:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 172, in close
   self.stop()

 File "G:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 184, in stop
   provider.stop()

 File "G:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\input\providers\wm_pen.py", line 111, in stop
   SetWindowLong_WndProc_wrapper(self.hwnd, self.old_windProc)

 File "G:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\input\providers\wm_common.py", line 122, in _closure
   oldAddr = func(hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, cast(wndProc, c_void_p).value)

ArgumentError: argument 3: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

here is the test code I got from https://kivy.org/#home

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

TestApp().run()
```

Restart the kernel is a feasible method, but this means that I must restart the kernel every time after runing the code. Is is normal?

**Environment**

```
active environment : base
active env location : G:\Miniconda3
shell level : 1
user config file : C:\Users\38477\.condarc
populated config files :
conda version : 4.7.9
conda-build version : not installed
python version : 3.7.3.final.0
virtual packages : __cuda=9.1
base environment : G:\Miniconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
 package cache : G:\Miniconda3\pkgs
                           C:\Users\38477\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\38477\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : G:\Miniconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\38477\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\38477\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
platform : win-64
user-agent : conda/4.7.9 requests/2.21.0 CPython/3.7.3 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17134
administrator : False
netrc file : None
offline mode : False
```

Comment: It sounds like this is probably a bug arising from re-running the app in the same process after a previous app has closed. It's a bug that this doesn't work, but it isn't used much so this has probably slipped through. Try using a new environment each time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used to have the same problem, if you are using spyder you have 3 option to solve it:

1.close and open again spyder each time you want to run the code

2.Consotools>preferences>run>execute in an external system terminal and then click ok. (run with F5)

3.Consoles>"Restart Kernel" before Run the App with F5 or F9

Answer (score 3):

You can't run Kivy application in the same python execution each time, that's why you needed to restart the kernel. I haven't used miniconda but I assume you have used Spyder. To run Kivy application smoothly in Spyder you can enable execution in external system.

Go to Tools >> Preferences. In preferences dialog box go to "Run" tab and enable "execute in external system terminal". 

Or you can restart the kernel each time before executing. I guess that will be disturbing.

I hope it helped.